# How to show product category names in wordpress search

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

My issue is that when I search any keyword it shows number of products like `showing 10 results`.

I want the category names in which this search result appears.

For example the result should be `10 results found in 3 categories: cat1, cat2, cat3`.

I am attaching an image so it may clear my issue: [image: search result]

Comment: improved language and formatting to make it more clear what the question was